# jBilling Error: An Invoice could not be generated

Tags: invoice

When I want to generate an invoice to an order following error is displayed:

**"There has been an error: 
An Invoice could not be generated. The purchase order does not have any applicable periods to be invoiced. 
Verify the data of the purchase order or contact customer service to review your business rules."**

I disabled pro-rating and I set following settings to plug-ins:

Invoice presentation 
com.sapienter.jbilling.server.pluggableTask.InvoiceCompositionTask

Billing process: order periods calculation 
com.sapienter.jbilling.server.pluggableTask.OrderPeriodTask

It is not working yet. Any Idea? help me quickly please.
Thanks a lot.

Comment: Thanks for your consideration!!!!!!! I solved it myself...

Comment: Hi,you have any idea to set default tolal in orderline in jbilling?

Answer (score 0):

when you create order, you will see period filed on order screen which is one time or monthly.

select one time and try to create order. if you select monthly then only one  invoice will create for that order because it is recurring order and then next bill set to next month.

if you want to create invoice again for same order then try to manage billing proces to next invoice date or update next bill date to curent month in purchase order table.